# Atomic Design - separation of implementation components from Atomic UI components

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, sass, software-design, atomic-design

Beginning to build a new UI library using the atomic design methodology we quickly ran into a problem when trying to categorise the smallest UI building blocks as atoms.  An example here might be a React component that might be say, `<SVGComponent />`.  Initially classified as an atom - it quickly became apparent that it probably wasn't. In terms of atomic design it wouldn't fit the vocabulary of being an atom - it is an implementation detail.  So an `<Icon />` component might fit the design classification of atom and the implementation of that component might be composed of an `<SVGComponent />`.  There are other examples of such components eg `<Font/>`.

Is there a common parlance for describing and classifying such components alongside an atomic ui library and where a dependency exists? Any thoughts generally on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in concepts of AD, but referring to the definition:

> Atoms are the smallest possible components, such as buttons, titles,
>   inputs or event color pallets, animations, and fonts. They can be
>   applied on any context, globally or within other components and
>   templates, besides having many states, such as this example of button:
>   disabled, hover, different sizes, etc.

So, if I understood the purpose of `<SVGComponent />` right, I don't quite agree that it doesn't fit the vocabulary of being an atom. Comparing it with the `<Button />` component (which is an atom), it can freely receive props like `'width'`, `'height'`, `'viewBox'`, etc.

As for the `<Icon />` component, it's not necessary to compose `<SVGComponent />` inside of it. You could try to pass something like `'src'` prop to `Icon`, which can be one of various types (img src, raw svg code, etc).

Just my two cents. Hope it helps.